# Plotting Historical Cointegration Values between two pairs

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, statsmodels

Here is the sample ADF test in python to check for Cointegration between two pairs. However the final result gives only the numeric value for co-integration. How to get the historical results of Co-integration.

Taken from http://www.leinenbock.com/adf-test-in-python/

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as stat
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as ts

x = np.random.normal(0,1, 1000)
y = np.random.normal(0,1, 1000)

def cointegration_test(y, x):
    result = stat.OLS(y, x).fit()    
    return ts.adfuller(result.resid)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want to test for expanding cointegration? Note that you should use `sm.tsa.coint` to test for cointegration. You could test for historical cointegrating relationship between realgdp and realdpi using pandas like so

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = sm.datasets.macrodata.load_pandas().data

def rolling_coint(x, y):
    yy = y[:len(x)]
    # returns only the p-value
    return sm.tsa.coint(x, yy)[1]

historical_coint = pd.expanding_apply(data.realgdp, rolling_coint, 
                                      min_periods=36, 
                                      args=(data.realdpi,))
```