# How to calculate expanding cointegration using latest pandas version?

Tags: python, pandas

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224842/plotting-historical-cointegration-values-between-two-pairs) post answer as template for the calculation, I get a depreciation warning:  FutureWarning: pd.expanding_apply is deprecated for Series and will be removed in a future version, replace with Series.expanding(min_periods=36).apply(args=,func=,kwargs=)

Old code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = sm.datasets.macrodata.load_pandas().data

def rolling_coint(x, y):
    yy = y[:len(x)]
    # returns only the p-value
    return sm.tsa.coint(x, yy)[1]

historical_coint = pd.expanding_apply(data.realgdp, rolling_coint, 
                                      min_periods=36, 
                                      args=(data.realdpi,))
```

How can I write the last line of code using Pandas 0.19.2?

I tried: `hist_coint = pd.DataFrame.expanding(min_periods=20).apply(data.realgdp, rolling_coint, args = (data.realdpi,))`

with the following error: TypeError: unbound method expanding() must be called with DataFrame instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Any ideas how to get this right?

Comment: Try: `hist_coint = data.expanding(...)`

Comment: Then I get: TypeError: apply() got multiple values for keyword argument 'args'

Comment: I believe, you could try `data.realgdp.expanding(min_periods=36).apply(rolling_coint, args=(data.realdpi,))` instead. Initialize `expanding()` on the passed series directly.

Comment: Then I get: TypeError: rolling_coint() takes exactly 2 arguments (204 given)

Comment: Note the trailing comma `','` in there. Else, these would pass the entire series thinking you've inputted it's column name. The args have to be a `tuple` I suppose.

Comment: Ahhhhh.. The devil is in the detail:) Works just fine now, thanks for your efforts! Post as answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for [**`Series.expanding().apply()`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.expanding.html) has been modified starting with `v0.18.0` as follows:

```
data.realgdp.expanding(min_periods=36).apply(rolling_coint, args=(data.realdpi,))
# <-SERIES->.expanding(..............).apply(<---FUNC---->, args=(......))
#                                                               / passed \ 
#                                                              / as tuple \
```